# Get seconds since epoch in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, time

Is there cross-platform solution to get seconds since epoch, for windows i use

```
long long NativesGetTimeInSeconds()
{
    return time (NULL);
}
```

But how to get on Linux?

Comment: What happens when you try that function on Linux?

Comment: Have you looked at Boost Date Time Library - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're already using it: [`std::time(0)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) (don't forget to `#include <ctime>`). However, whether `std::time` actually returns the time since epoch isn't  specified in the standard ([C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), referenced by the C++ standard):

> ### 7.27.2.4 The `time` function
>
> #### Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <time.h>
> time_t time(time_t *timer);
> ```
>
> #### Description
>
> The time function determines the current calendar time.  ***The encoding of the value is unspecified.*** [emphasis mine]

For C++, C++11 and later provide [`time_since_epoch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch). However, before C++20 the epoch of [`std::chrono::system_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) was unspecified and therefore possibly non-portable in previous standards.

Still, on Linux the `std::chrono::system_clock` will usually use Unix Time even in C++11, C++14 and C++17, so you can use the following code:

```
#include <chrono>

// make the decltype slightly easier to the eye
using seconds_t = std::chrono::seconds;

// return the same type as seconds.count() below does.
// note: C++14 makes this a lot easier.
decltype(seconds_t().count()) get_seconds_since_epoch()
{
    // get the current time
    const auto now     = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    // transform the time into a duration since the epoch
    const auto epoch   = now.time_since_epoch();

    // cast the duration into seconds
    const auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(epoch);
    
    // return the number of seconds
    return seconds.count();
}
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to give you the time since epoch. The documentation just says that this is 'usually' the case. Not portable.

Comment: To clarify, several years later:
As of C++20, *std::chrono::system_clock* (the latter method demonstrated) is now guaranteed by the standard to be based on the Unix Epoch.

Comment: @JaminGrey Thanks for the heads up. I added a note about C++20.

Answer (score 16):

In C.

```
time(NULL);
```

In C++.

```
std::time(0);
```

And the return value of time is : **time_t** not *long long*

Answer (score 3):

**The Simple, Portable, and Proper Approach**

```
#include <ctime>

long CurrentTimeInSeconds()
{
     return (long)std::time(0); //Returns UTC in Seconds
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The native Linux function for getting time is `gettimeofday()` [there are some other flavours too], but that gets you the time in seconds and nanoseconds, which is more than you need, so I would suggest that you continue to use `time()`. [Of course, `time()` is implemented by calling `gettimeofday()` somewhere down the line - but I don't see the benefit of having two different pieces of code that does exactly the same thing - and if you wanted that, you'd be using `GetSystemTime()` or some such on Windows [not sure that's the right name, it's been a while since I programmed on Windows]

Comment: There is also `clock_gettime` and reading `time(7)` man page is helpful

Comment: And it still fetches nanoseconds:
http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.7.1/arch/x86/vdso/vclock_gettime.c#L149
called from 
http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.7.1/arch/x86/vdso/vclock_gettime.c#L175

(assuming we're talking x86, at least)